Cliffhanger ending?
I'm writing a first book in a series and so far I have planned out the plot for the first and second book, not sure if I write more after that. The thing is all the issues in the first book are solved at the end but there is a revelation made by one of the characters that I am planning to use as a last sentence of the novel and reveal the resolution in the second through flashbacks. I feel like this is the right way and I cannot imagine it differently. On the other hand, I feel like this would give me negative feedback and people would think I did it just for them to buy the next book. What do you think?

It is natural that the first book in a series ends without all issues having been resolved. Otherwise, writing a second volume wouldn't make much sense!
A volume in a series should have some kind of closure. One narrative arc will come to its end. The Lord of the Rings is a good example of this (that I like to use because it is so well-known). At the end of book one, the Hobbits reach Rivendell. The journey there comes to an end. But the story continues, because the Nazgul (and Sauron) haven't been defeated and the Ring still poses a problem that needs to be resolved.
It is good practice, though, to clearly announce that your book is one of a series and that the story spans several volumes, so readers don't start reading expecting this to be a standalone. If I intentionally buy the first volume in a series, a partially open end won't disappoint me.

Adding to this: one way to help a series feel more natural is to integrate some of your "cliffhangers" earlier.  If cutting the last paragraph of your story out removes all the cliffhangers without impacting the resolution of the book in any way, then can easily comes across as "forced".  If one of your cast realise an ongoing mystery while also figuring out something important to the current plot in the penultimate chapter, that may flow better.  (e.g. "the kidnappers are hiding in the Old Manor House!  But, how did they get access to it?" can set up a hidden ally of the antagonists…)

Just to pick some nits, there was no "Fellowship of the Ring" when Aragorn and the Hobbits reached Rivendell. It was formed at Rivendell with the addition of more participants to take the ring to Mordor.


I feel like this would give me negative feedback and people would think I did it just for them to buy the next book.

That's what a cliffhanger is supposed to do - it's supposed to make you want to see what happens next. Anyone criticizing your novel solely for ending on a cliffhanger, without regard for the quality of the cliffhanger, is frankly being unreasonable.
There are, of course, situations in which a story might rightfully be criticized for ending on a cliffhanger:

The cliffhanger cuts the story off at an awkward point, often right before the climax. Halo 2 is an infamous example, with it ending just as Master Chief leaves to "finish the fight".
The cliffhanger ends on such a bleak note that the reader finds it hard to imagine how the story can progress from there without veering into deus ex machina territory.
The cliffhanger never gets resolved properly, either because a sequel is never released (The Italian Job being an iconic example), or because the sequel just glosses over it or outright ignores it.

The first two don't sound like they apply to your novel, and since you already have the second novel planned out, the last one shouldn't apply either, so long as both novels actually get released. So go for it!

I think Clara might be concerned that putting that sentence at the end to introduce the cliff-hanger might make it seem contrived or obvious.

Cliffhangers as a general rule are expected in the first book of a series. After all, there should be some threads left open-ended for later books to build upon. Otherwise, there's nothing keeping the reader invested in the series and no reason for them to seek out the second book.
That said, there are good ways and bad ways to do cliffhangers. A good way is for the book to end in a way that neatly wraps up the narrative of that story while leaving the overall narrative still in motion:

...Bill, Wade, and Susan slumped down on the old sofa with a thud, too tired to care about the cloud of dust kicked up from their effort. The evil Dr. Jerome had been caught and was on his way to prison, so the town would be safe for one more day. In the morning, they would read through his notes to find out who he was working for, and the real battle against the remaining members of the League of Doom would begin in earnest. But for now, all they really wanted was the first full night's sleep they'd had in weeks.

The story leaves room for a sequel while still wrapping things up in a satisfying way, and it allows the book to come to a natural conclusion.
A bad way, however, is to wrap up the entire narrative with a neat little bow, and then at the last second introduce a new twist out of nowhere:

...They had done it. Bill, Wade, and Susan had defeated the evil Dr. Jerome, and the town was finally safe. They sat down on the couch, ready to enjoy the first full night's sleep they'd had in weeks, when suddenly Wade's phone rang with the alert of an incoming text message. The message had no sender, but the group felt a chill creep over their bones when they read the contents: "Enjoy your rest. We are coming. Sincerely, The League of Doom."

In this example, the reader is thrown a curveball just in time for the story to end and is offered no further explanation or context. Who is the League of Doom? Why are we only finding out about them just now? What impact do they have in the world that makes me feel the need to care about them? Far from hyping up the next book, the sudden revelation feels forced and contrived, and it makes the ending of the story feel wholly unnatural.

You have to love writing that ties everything up and down in the last possible moment, the last possible paragraph, the last possible sentence, the last possible WORD!  DOOM!  Great example.  (I want to read this now.)

Sometimes cliffhangers are just throwaway lines, not intended to be followed by anything else, nor even taken seriously.  To take a famous movie example: “Roads?  Where we're going, we don't need roads…” was originally just that — a funny line to end what was then a stand-alone movie.
However, the movie was so popular that a couple of sequels followed, and so they then needed to back up that throwaway remark with some serious film-making, turning it into a genuine cliff-hanger!
I think both cases can apply to novels too: you could have a final sentence that seems to change everything as a deliberate lead-in to sequel, or as an obvious gag.
And there's a third possibility: a final revelation that's purely intended to shed new light on what went before, to cause the reader to re-evaluate the events of the book.  This case is meant seriously, but doesn't need to lead on to any sequel (though it can).
As other answers have said, in all cases you need to have had some narrative closure by that point, or readers (or viewers) will feel cheated.  If it leads into a sequel, readers should already have been led to expect that (e.g. from marketing, cover blurb, or ‘…Part One’ in the title).  Or if it's a throwaway line done purely for effect, then it should be clearly recognisable as such — which is probably easier to do with a light-hearted book than a more serious one.
One other point to bear in mind if a cliffhanger is meant seriously: it must be consistent with what went before.  You can get away with throwing in a major revelation with little or no preparation or foreshadowing, even (especially!) if it makes readers re-evaluate everything they've already read — but not if it makes a nonsense of it.  If readers feel that events in the book simply wouldn't have happened given the revelation, or that one or more characters just wouldn't ring true, or that the protagonist's struggle would be meaningless, then it'll seem like an obvious trick, and they'll feel cheated.


On the other hand, I feel like this would give me negative feedback

On the contrary, you are doing 100% the correct approach.
(But do remember that ultimately everything is character driven, to put it cynically characters, not plots, sell books and movies. Plot is just something that reveals character, soul.)

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
